# Dense linear order on any infinite set

Tags: order-theory

**The problem:**

*Prove that there is a dense linear order on any infinite set X: that is, a linear order such that whenever $x < y$, there is a $z \in X$ such that $x < z < y$. [Hint: consider $\mathbb{Q}\times X$].*

I've tried proving this using Zorn's lemma, but it doesn't get me anywhere. I don't see how the tip could be used, maybe something with the property that between two rationals there always is an irrational..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axiom of choice is needed here, of course. So going through Zorn's lemma is somehow necessary. But applying it "directly" is not the best course of action.

Here are two options:

1. Use these two facts in conjunction:

   - Every set can be linearly ordered (that is a consequence of Zorn's lemma),
   - and $|\Bbb Q\times X|=|X|$ for any infinite set $X$ (that is another consequence of Zorn's lemma).

   Now use the lexicographic ordering on $\Bbb Q\times X$ (using the first fact), and the bijection you have to $X$ (using the second fact) to define a linear ordering on $X$ which is dense.
2. Use the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem to prove that every theory with an infinite model has an infinite model of any cardinality. Since $\Bbb Q$ is a model of "dense linear ordering" which is infinite, there is one of any cardinality. In particular, $|X|$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The second option uses the 'upward' Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Could you please work out the first option a little bit more? I'm having trouble defining the linear ordening on $X$. Should I just order everything in $X$ like the pre-images of every element of $X$ are ordered by the lexicographic ordering on $\mathbb{Q} \times X$?

Comment: You don't *define* a linear ordering on $X$. You use Zorn's lemma, either to prove that there is a linear ordering, or a well-ordering, or whatever. Then you just use transport of structure with the second part.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Is it not enough to say: there is a linear order on $X$ (by Zorn's lemma) and we define it as $\cdots$?

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure to which part you meant by "define a linear order on $X$". Do you accept that there is *any* linear ordering on $X$, and having problems defining one from a bijection of $X$ with $\Bbb Q\times X$?

Comment: Yes. So the one I was thinking was a "corresponding" between the lexicographic order on the direct product, and the linear order on the image $X$.

Comment: Yes. If you have *any* structure on a set $A$, and a bijection $f\colon A\to B$, you can define an isomorphic structure on $B$ by using $f$ to transport constants/functions/relations from $A$ to $B$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Comment: Okay I understand it now. Thanks for the clear and useful answers.

Comment: I am also stuck on this problem. So I have a linear order on $\mathbb{Q}$ and one on X and I used those two to define a lexicographic order on $\mathbb{Q} \times X$. Then I used the bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \times X$ to X and defined a (new) order on X by defining x<y iff the pre-image of x is < the pre-image of y w.r.t. to the order on $\mathbb{Q} \times X$. This is obviously a linear order on X, but why it is dense?

Comment: @anoniem: Why is the order on $\Bbb Q\times X$ dense?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Is that so? I have no idea...

Comment: Can anyone help me please? I'm stuck on this for days

Comment: @kasaf karagila, can you explain me please?